# Proof of convergence for Customer Retention Rate Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to practice and see old notes of Calculus 1, but I can't still find out the reason why my series converge.

Retention Rate is a ratio that defines how many customers will shop again after the first purchase in a fixed period of time.

The starting conditions are:
100 customers at t0
Retention Rate is =0.4
New customers on t1=10 and this value is a constant for t2,...tn

So we have this series:

t0=100

t1=100*0.4+10

t2=(100*0.4+10)*0.4+10

...

tn=Something*0.4+10

1. Why Converge?
2. How to calculate the final value fixed Retention rate, New Customers at each time interval and starting base?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  The easier your questions are to read, the better the response you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally,
if
$t_{n+1}
=at_n+b
$,
then
$\dfrac{t_{n+1}}{a^{n+1}}
=\dfrac{at_n+b}{a^{n+1}}
=\dfrac{t_n}{a^{n}}+\dfrac{b}{a^{n+1}}
$.

Letting
$s_n
=\dfrac{t_n}{a^{n}}
$,
$s_{n+1}
=s_n+\dfrac{b}{a^{n+1}}
$
or
$s_{n+1}-s_n
=\dfrac{b}{a^{n+1}}
$.

Summing from $1$ to $m-1$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(s_{n+1}-s_n)
=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\dfrac{b}{a^{n+1}}
$
or
$s_m-s_1
=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\dfrac{b}{a^{n+1}}
$
or
$\dfrac{t_m}{a^m}
=\dfrac{t_1}{a}
+\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}ba^{-n-1}
=\dfrac{t_1}{a}
+\sum_{n=2}^{m}ba^{-n}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
t_m
&=a^{m-1}t_1
+a^m\sum_{n=2}^{m}ba^{-n}\\
&=a^{m-1}t_1
+b\sum_{n=2}^{m}a^{n-m}\\
&=a^{m-1}t_1
+b\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}a^{n}\\
&=a^{m-1}t_1
+b\dfrac{1-a^{m-1}}{1-a}
\qquad\text{if } a \ne 1\\
\end{array}
$

If $|a| < 1$ then
$t_m \to \dfrac{b}{1-a}
$.

If $|a| > 1$ then
$\dfrac{t_m}{a^{m-1}}
=t_1+b\dfrac{a^{-m+1}-1}{1-a}
\to t_1+\dfrac{b}{a-1}
$.

If $a = 1$ then
$t_m
= t_1+(m-1)b
$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$t_{n+1}=.4t_n+10$$  Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=t$.  What must the value of $t$ be?

As for convergence, show that $t<t_{n+1}<t_n$, and remember that a monotonically decreasing sequence (*not* series) that is bounded below converges.

Comment: I feel so dumb :) For the first question, the answer seems to be t because it's a costant. Based on that I would say that the answer is 50, but I think to be complitely wrong, empirically It's 16.6

Comment: In another example that I made to understand better. With t0=1000 Retention Rate=0.7 and Constant Value 1000, It converges to 3333. But I am very rude, I have done as a proof on Excel and I am trying to understand why

Comment: Take the limit as $n\to\infty$ on both sides.  Then solve for $t$.